# Highcharts Render Animation Reverse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, highcharts

I wanted to know if Highcharts library allows animation for rendering when charts are removed. (or hide or any..)

To make my question more sense, I have attached a image of a donut chart while it renders.

[image: Donut chart rendering]

Left image shows animation direction when chart is rendering. Animation renders clockwise direction from 12 o'clock.

Right image shows my desire animation where animation renders anti-clockwise and removes (or hide) charts and will be left empty. (This is what I'm seek for.. if it's available)

The reason why I seek for this is because I wanted to keep the consistancy when I render chart and hide chart. I love the nature of Highchart's smooth display, animation and it would be nice to have reverse render animation..

Hope anyone knows if this feature is implemented or not available..

Thank you for your time to read this.

Regards,

Danny C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's not supported, but possible to achieve by wrapping animate function for pie chart. See: http://jsfiddle.net/dK9CD/79/

```
// Hack Highcharts to provide counter-clockwise animation for pies
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype, 'animate', function (proceed, init) {
    this.startAngleRad += Math.PI * 2;    
    proceed.call(this, init);    
});


var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1,2,3,4,5],
        startAngle: 0
    }]

});
```

Comment: Wow!! impressive! Thank you for your demo!. Just a little further step continued from this question, is current demo applicable with in a way that, from existing fully rendered donut chart to do a reverse animation to shrink and vanish? Sorry to ask for more..

Comment: What do you mean by shrink & vanish? You wanted reversed animation, right? See for donut: http://jsfiddle.net/dK9CD/80/

Comment: Sorry for lack of description.. I have a image that may help your understanding. (http://i.imgur.com/3ljmSPM.png) in this image, animation starts from anti-clockwise and parts of donut chart is fading as animation goes. Which it was my intention of saying "reverse animation". Once again, sorry for lack of info and please let me know if it is achievable.. Thank you so much

Comment: You want to hide full pie with reversed animation! Unfortunately this is not supported. In general, you have two options: hide slice-by-slice or remove that points. But it won't be as smooth as initial animation.